# Diferença performática de Any() e Count()

Tags: c#, .net, linq, desempenho

Quando preciso verificar se uma *collection* tem ou não elementos qual dos dois métodos será mais rápido, `.Count() =! 0` ou `.Any()`?

Já ouvi falar que o `.Count()` pode ser mais rápido em alguns casos. Mas verificando o [código fonte](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs), o método `Any()` me pareceu melhor de ser usado.

Existe também a possibilidade de ter uma condição dentro do método, nesse caso pode mudar qual dos dois é mais rápido?

E quando é usado em um `DbSet`, a *query* gerada pelo `.Any()` é diferente da `.Count()` imagino eu. Mas a em questão de performance o `Any()` ainda continua na frente?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Você tem razão. Pela forma que esses métodos trabalham, analisando item por item de uma coleção, há mais vantagens em usar o `Any()` ([fonte](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/AnyAll.cs,8788153112b7ffd0)) quando você pode fazer isto.

Com o `Count()` ([fonte](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Count.cs,41ef9e39e54d0d0b)) você está dizendo que deseja saber quantos itens existem dentro da coleção (ou um subconjunto dela que já foi decidido por outros métodos do LINQ). A única forma de saber isto é percorrer todos os itens.

As pessoas costumam usar esta forma porque estão acostumadas com coleções puras onde você pode pedir o `Count` (a propriedade e não método) e tem a resposta praticamente sem custo, afinal na coleção pura, sem ter passado por uma expressão LINQ, a quantidade de itens é algo controlado pela classe e está lá disponível sempre de forma confiável e rápida.

No LINQ não tem essa facilidade, tem que percorrer tudo e contar, pelo menos em subconjuntos. Claro que pode haver otimizações que pegam a contagem armazenada na coleção mas não na implementação padrão (LINQ-to-Objects faz isto). E pode ser que você queira a contagem mesmo, oque neste caso use-o.

Mas muitas vezes as pessoas só querem saber **se existe** um item pelo menos. A maneira como todos acostumaram é verificar se a contagem é maior que zero. Bem intuitivo, funciona e em coleções puras é rápido.

Mas convenhamos, se quer saber só se existe um item, não quer saber quantos tem, basta achar o primeiro item e você tem a sua resposta. Não precisa olhar para os outros itens. A resposta já será verdadeira e nada que aconteça nos outros itens poderá mudar o resultado.

No pior caso do [`Any()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), que é encontrar nada, a performance será a mesma do [`Count()`](https://Learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Em todas as outras será melhor, em muitos, absurdamente melhor.

O `Count()` do LINQ, sem otimizações, será sempre complexidade linear, já o `Any()` será entre constante e linear, o que muda muito.

O fato de ter uma condição que é um substituto do `Where()` não afeta em nada diretamente. Indiretamente pode ajudar o `Any()` porque fica mais fácil ele ter uma condição para encerrar a busca primeiro. No caso da otimização que falei acima, também não é possível quando há uma condição como parâmetro, assim como já não seria se usasse uma condição anterior, com um `Where()`, por exemplo.

Eu não consegui achar um fonte confiável e não conheço bem o Entity Framework para cravar uma resposta, mas pela natureza de como ele funciona, eu acredito que o mesmo continua valendo na maioria dos casos. A consulta LINQ será transformada em uma consulta SQL que terá que percorrer as linhas para contar ou achar um existente. Porém um banco de dados específico pode saber como pegar a contagem das linhas de forma otimizada em algumas situações. Aí o `Count()` pode eventualmente ser mais rápido. Mas note que depende do banco usado, do fornecedor LINQ dele e da situação específica. Não conte muito com isto, considere sorte quando acontecer.

Se precisar da performance mesmo, perceber que ela é fundamental e consegue ter ganhos, vai ter que fazer um código para gerenciar a escolha. Por padrão vá sempre de `Any()` quando só quer saber se existe.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: E quando é usado em um DbSet, a query gerada pelo .Any() continua sendo melhor?

Comment: @Hokos boa pergunta, vou tentar descobri pra você . O que já posso adiantar é que pode variar mesmo. Lembrando que estes métodos LINQ são contextuais de acordo com o tipo de coleção que você está usando, então a implementação do DBSet pode eventualmente não ser a mesma que você listou.

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta e quando descobrir você complementa sua resposta.

Comment: Hoje é dias dos negativos pra cima de mim. Espero que tenha um motivo. Espero que a pessoa mostre o que tem errado.

Answer (score 13):

Depende do tipo da enumeração.

Se for baseada em [`ICollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/System.Collections.ICollection(v=vs.110).aspx), [`.Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.collections.icollection.count(v=vs.110).aspx) (propriedade, não método) é mais rápido porque o valor já é previamente calculado dentro da estrutura (otimizado). [`.Any()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/Bb337697(v=VS.100).aspx) requer usar a sequência [`GetEnumerator()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator(v=vs.110).aspx) / [`MoveNext()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext(v=vs.110).aspx) / `Dispose()`.

Já em quaisquer outras enumerações, [`.Count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/Bb338038(v=VS.110).aspx) (agora método) itera todos os elementos. `Any()` tem o fluxo interrompido ao localizar a primeira sequência, portanto, é mais rápido que `.Count()`

Em resumo, `Any()` se comporta melhor na maioria dos casos.

Comment: Me parece que muitas vezes existe uma confusão entre o .Count e o .Count() por isso talvez muitas pessoas achem o .Count() mais rápido. Mas tudo isso só confirma o que eu imaginei.